# operator does not exist: json - text[] error in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to delete some rows in a Postgresql table with this query:

```
DELETE FROM log_sp_montreal_test.person_contact 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM log_sp_montreal_test.person_contact limit 100)
```

I'm using PgAdminIII, but when I run it in the SQL Editor, I get this weird error:

```
    ERROR:  operator does not exist: json - text[]
LINE 1: SELECT row_to_json(OLD.*)::json - ignored::TEXT[]
                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT row_to_json(OLD.*)::json - ignored::TEXT[]
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function log_sp_montreal_test.add_journalization_entry() line 17 at assignment
********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: json - text[]
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function log_sp_montreal_test.add_journalization_entry() line 17 at assignment
```

The id is a uuid, but what is this error and how can I run it?

Comment: There is a trigger defined on the table and the trigger function `log_sp_montreal_test.add_journalization_entry()` raises the error. Analyse the function.